# AWK print command for specific rows

Tags: unix, awk

I have millions of records in my file, what i need to do is print columns 1396 to 1400 for specific number of rows, and if i can get this in excel or notepad.

Tried with this command

```
awk {print $1396,$1397,$1398,$1399,$1400}' file_name
```

But this is running for each row.

Comment: You have to use `NR` to indicate the line number `awk 'NR==1 {print $2}'` prints the 2nd column on line 1. If the number of lines is big or variable, you may have to use another approach. Give more information so we can address this better.

Comment: say i want to print those columns 1396 to 1400 for rows 50 to 100

Comment: It would be helpful to include a sample of the input file. You probably need to tell awk how the columns are separated.

Comment: And PLEASE don't post an example that's 150 lines by 2,000 columns! 6x8 or similar should demonstrate nicely.

Answer (score 7):

You need a condition to specify which rows to apply the action to:

```
awk '<<condition goes here>> {print $1396,$1397,$1398,$1399,$1400}' file_name
```

For example, to do this only for rows 50 to 100:

```
awk 'NR >= 50 && NR <= 100 {print $1396,$1397,$1398,$1399,$1400}' file_name
```

(Depending on what you want to do, you can also have much more complicated selection patterns than this.)

Here's a simpler example for testing:

```
awk 'NR >= 3 && NR <= 5 {print $2, $3}'
```

If I run this on an input file containing

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 a b 6
4 c d 7
5 e f 8
6 7 8 9
```

I get the output

```
a b
c d
e f
```

Comment: or is there a way to print say 1k records in notepad ?

Comment: Files with thousands of rows and columns can definitely be difficult to work with.  Extracting just the rows and columns you want, using a tool like `awk`, is a very good approach.  Don't give up yet -- I'm sure we can get it to work.  Did you try the small example on a small file?

Comment: You said "the output is blank records".  It's likely this was because awk didn't see any columns up in the 139x range.  Are you sure the file has that many columns?  Are you sure the columns are separated with the column separators that awk expects (typically space or tab)?

Comment: yeah tried with two to three rows but then its still blank output. My record is fixed length format, will that have any impact on this command ?

Comment: yeah i have 1628 columns in my file and each row is a fixed length format

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "fixed length format".  Try the simpler example I just added to my answer.

Comment: but shouldn't you be getting the entire 2nd and third column

Comment: Nope, only on rows 3-5.